# Extend existing protocol in order to modify delegates parameters in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I don't know if this is possible.

Is there a way to extend CLLocationManager and its protocol (CLLLocationManagerDelegate) in order to receive in its delegate didRangeBeacon, a custom CLBeaconRegion (a class which extends from CLBeaconRegion) and that the beacons Array contains, instead of the regular CLBeacon instance, an instance from another a class that extends from CLBeacon.

Right now what I have is an implementation inside didRangeBeacon delegate that prepare instances of my custom CLBeaconRegion and CLBeacon classes and call a custom didRangeBeacon method of the protocol I've defined in the .h file (which looks really close to the regular CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol in terms of methods and properties)

Maybe I am not explaining my self. Here it what I have:

Inside my customDelegate .h I have:

```
@class MyCustomManager;

    @protocol MyCustomManagerDelegate <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

    @optional
    - (void)myManager:(MyCustomManager*)myManager didFoundBeacon:(MyCustomBeacon *)beacon inRegion:(MyCustomBeaconRegion *)region;
    - (void)myManager:(MyCustomManager*)myManager didLostBeacon:(MyCustomBeacon *)beacon inRegion:(MyCustomBeaconRegion *)region;
    - (void)myManager:(MyCustomManager*)myManager didEnterRegion:(MyCustomBeaconRegion *)region;
    - (void)myManager:(MyCustomManager*)myManager didExitRegion:(MyCustomBeaconRegion *)region;
    - (void)myManager:(MyCustomManager*)myManager didRangeBeacon:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(MyCustomBeaconRegion *)region;

    @end

@interface MyCustomManager : NSObject  <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) id<MyCustomManagerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then in my .m I have:

```
@implementation MyCustomManager

    -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(MyCustomBeaconRegion *)region{
    //my code goes here
    }

@end
```

If I debug my app and use a breakpoint to check inside the didRangeBeacons, I am still receiving CLBeaconRegion instead MyCustomBeaconRegion. And checking the first beacon properties in the debug console, is still says CLBeacon and not MyCustomBeacon, however I see my custom beacon class properties listed (It appears a CLBeacon first and then my extend class properties)

I know I am doing something wrong for sure but I don't know where. I've used inheritance many times but not with protocol/delegates and this CLLocationManager. I don't know if what I am asking is even possible.

I would like to know if is possible to override default delegate methods so they are invoked using my custom classes instead the default protocol parameter classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely not possible. System frameworks are not open for modification.

Comment: Ok, that is what I was thinking, but googling it, I missunderstand a few concepts.

Thanks anyway, I think I was going crazy today :)

Comment: Now, you could probably create your own location manager that has an instance of the system location manager inside it. Your location manager would be the delegate of the system location manager, and would take beacon regions from the system framework, convert them to your custom subclass, and forward them to ITs delegate.

Comment: Hello Duncan, indeed, that's what I've done. I was just refactoring my code and I got confused after thinking too much hahaha :)